# Using 68-95-99.7% rule to find that $P(\vert Z \vert > 3)$ is approximately $0.003$; the exact value is $2 \cdot \Phi (-3)$.

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, standard-deviation

When reading an example of bounds on a Normal tail probability, I came across this:

> Let $Z \sim N(0, 1)$. By the 68-95-99.7% rule, we know that $P(\vert Z \vert > 3)$ is approximately $0.003$; the exact value is $2 \cdot \Phi (-3)$.

In [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule) Wikipedia article on the 68-95-99.7 rule, it gives the example of

> $${\displaystyle \Pr(\mu -2\sigma \leq X\leq \mu +2\sigma )=\Phi (2)-\Phi (-2)\approx 0.9772-(1-0.9772)\approx 0.9545}$$

I'm presuming that this is $P(\vert Z \vert) \ge 2)$. So it has that $P(\vert Z \vert) \ge 2) = 2\Phi(2) - 1 \approx 0.9545$.

[This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function) Wikipedia article gives the standard normal CDF as

> $${\displaystyle \Phi (x)={\frac {1}{\sqrt {2\pi }}}\int _{-\infty }^{x}e^{-t^{2}/2}\,dt}$$

This is the formula we would to calculate either of these two values.

Given this, how is it that $P(\vert Z \vert > 3) = 2 \Phi(-3)$?  Shouldn't it be something like $P(\vert Z \vert > 3) = 1 - 2 \Phi(-3)$? I think I might be getting confused with the symmetry properties of the Normal distribution here?

Thank you.

Comment: The thing in the second box is $P(|Z|\leq 2)$, not $\geq$.

Comment: @Randall Oh, my mistake. So then it is $P(\vert Z \vert) \le 2) = 2\Phi(2) - 1 \approx 0.9545$. And so, for the other one, we get $P(\vert Z \vert) > 3) = 1 - (2\Phi(-3) - 1) = -2 \Phi(-3)$? But $-2 \Phi(-3) = 1 - (-2 \Phi(3)) = 1 + 2 \Phi(3)$ by the symmetry of the Normal distribution, right?

Comment: Eh, calculus, why did you delete your answer? Was it incorrect?

Comment: @DomFomello Sorry. No the answer is correct. The key point is to know how to use the symmetry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have

$= P (|Z|\le z)=P(-z\le Z\le z ) \\
                   = \Phi(z)-\Phi(-z)\\
                   = 1-\Phi(-z)-\Phi(-z), \ \ \textrm{due symmetry}\\
                   = 1-2\Phi(-z)$

That means that $P (|Z|\geq z)=1-P (|Z|\le z)=1-(1-2\Phi(-z))=2\Phi(-z)$